# javac: invalid target release: 1.8 on Mac when executing Maven command

Tags: java, macos, maven, compilation, javac

I am trying to run automation test on Mac. I installed Maven and java, jdk as following:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

and Maven:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

When I executed Maven command, I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] use -help for a list of possible options
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I searched on here, there's one accepted solution is this:

```
sudo cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar /Library/Java/Extensions/
```

I executed this command, but nothing happened! I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What are the outputs of `which java` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: For me, upgrading from Maven 3.2.5 to 3.3.3 did the trick.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, figure out where 1.8 Java is installed by running the command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

Then, set your JAVA_HOME environment variable by running the command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<whatever the output from the previous command was>
```

Maven should work afterwards, at least in that terminal window.

You'll have to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable in your profile if you don't want to have to run these commands every time you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't done so already, use the `maven-compiler-plugin` to determine the Java version to use within Maven.  Put this in your `pom.xml` file (change the `<source/>` and `<target/>` version to the JDK version you require):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(If you already have a `<build/>` and/or `<plugins/`> section, add the `<plugin/>` portion, only.)